# How to modify a List<Vector3> property

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a c# class for unity that has a public property which is a List called points. 
Which I declared like.

```
Public List<Vector3 > points{get; set;}
```

I want to make a translate method  that adds a Vector3 to each element.  The problem I am having is that the within the method the values are updating properly but after the method returns points is unchanged.  I think I am modying a copy of points and not the actual list.
Here's what I have tried:

I have made a new list local to the method called newPoints and did this.

```
public void translate(Vector3 vect)
{
    List<Vector3> newPoints = new List <Vector3>(); 
    foreach(Vector3 v in points) 
    {
        newPoints. Add(v +vect) ;//vect is a Vector3 parameter 
    }
    points =newPoints;
}
```

I have also tried

```
int count = 0;
foreach(Vector3 v in points) 
{
    points[count] = v + vect;
    count++;
}
points =newPoints;
```

If anyone could take pity on a newbie and help me out it would be great.  If there is generally better method of accomplishing the same thing I would like to know that too but I also want to understand why this isn't working in case the same issue ever comes up again.

Comment: In your second block of code, you don't need `points =newPoints;`

Comment: "but after the method returns points is unchanged" - that won't happen with either of the methods you've shown.

Comment: Thanks for your help I will have to look elsewhere then I just wanted to see if the way I was trying to do it was wrong.

Comment: Well you don't *need* to create a new list. You can modify the list in-place with a `for` loop. But your current code should work in terms of modifying `points` to refer to a new list. Perhaps wherever you were looking was referring to the original list? It's hard to help further when we don't know how you diagnosed that "points was unchanged".

Answer (score 1):

Two things to note:

- the list `points` should be initialized somewhere (call the constructor of list).
- Probably just a typo, but `public` should not have a capital 'P'

This worked perfectly on my computer:

```
public List<Vector3> points{ get; set; }

private void Start()
{
    points = new List<Vector3>(); // initialize the list

    // Add dummy values to test
    points.Add(new Vector3(1, 2, 3));
    points.Add(new Vector3(4, 5, 6));
    points.Add(new Vector3(7, 8, 9));

    printPoints(); // display

    translate(Vector3.one); // translate with (1,1,1)

    printPoints(); // display again
}

public void translate(Vector3 vect)
{
    // Just an old school for loop instead of foreach so you can modify points directly
    for (int i = 0; i < points.Count; i++)
    {
        points[i] += vect;
    }
}

public void printPoints()
{
    foreach (Vector3 v in points)
    {
        Debug.Log(v);
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
(1.0,2.0,3.0)
(4.0,5.0,6.0)
(7.0,8.0,9.0)

(2.0,3.0,4.0)
(5.0,6.0,7.0)
(8.0,9.0,10.0)
```